# How to save files to cloud storages like google drive from a web url in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, google-api-nodejs-client

I am working on a nodejs app and I want to add a feature of saving a file from a web url directly to cloud storage services like google drive. I am thinking of downloading the file to my nodejs server first and then upload from server to the drive, but i am not sure if it is the best way to achieve the goal, is it the fastest and most efficient way?

Please suggest me the best possible way.

Thanks